# Php stopped working inside a while with MySQL connection - XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem in this code and I'm not able to understand or find it.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'magia');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed, reasons: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
$SQLQuery = $mysqli->query("select name, area as Area,`range`,material_costs from spells");

if ($SQLQuery->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table border: 1px>";                                                       
echo "<tr><td>Name<td>Information 1<td>Information 2<td>Information3</td>";
$increment = 0;
while($row = $SQLQuery->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" .$increment." - ".$row["name"]. "<td>" . $row["Area"]. " <td>" . $row["range"]. "<td>" . $row["material_costs"]. "</td>";

    $increment++;    //this is here just to count the effective number of results it prints
}
echo "</table><br>";
} else {
echo "no results";
}
   $mysqli->close();
```

Short story it prints a table with the data I get from the database. Or at least it should; when it's almost done it stops and it doesn't give me a reason; it literally stops printing strings without even finishing them. I googled for solutions but no result helped me. I checked both main problem causes: `max_execution_time` and the error log. I tried to raise the first (to 120) and I got no change, I checked the second and it doesn't say anything relevant to my problem.

Does anyone have a clue? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Following many of the comments and the answers I found no solution, still I encountered an even stranger behavior; whenever I add code, I get more records. The actual code is here:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'magia');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed, reasons: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
$SQLQuery = $mysqli->query("select name, area as Area,`range`,material_costs from spells");

if ($SQLQuery->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table border: 1px>";
    echo "<tr><td>Name<td>Information 1<td>Information 2<td>Information3</td></tr>";
    $increment = 0;
    $start = microtime (true);
    while($row = $SQLQuery->fetch_assoc()) {
        $time = microtime (true);
        $time -= $start;
        $memory = memory_get_peak_usage (true);
        echo "<tr><td>" .$increment." - ".$memory." - ".$time." - ".$row["name"]. "<td>" . $row["Area"]. " <td>" . $row["range"]. "<td>" . $row["material_costs"]. "</td></tr>";
        $increment++;    //this is here just to count the effective number of results it prints
    }
    echo "</table><br>";
} else {
    echo "no results";
}
$mysqli->close();
```

That is. I also noticed that the data i receive fluctuates a bit, sometimes it's a little longer, sometimes it's a little shorter. I'm very confused about this.

EDIT - Update of the situation:
The problem still exist. I tried to apply any of your suggestions.
`set_time_limit` is set to 0.
I don't receive any notice of any kind of error. Anywhere.
By putting the query in MySQL Workbench it returns the correct amount of data.
I believe this problem exist in either PHP or in my PHP configuration, yet that is the default except for `set_time_limit`.
Is anybody aware of this problem in their configurations?

Comment: How many records get printed, how many are in your table? Maybe script timeout?

Comment: In the database I got 2208 records, the script shows me the firsts 2093.

Comment: Your html is broken. Use <td>...</td> to correctly define a table column. Use <tr>...</tr> to enclose all columns of one table row. Maybe you just can't see the results. Press Ctrl+u in browser an insepct html code to see if all your data is there.

Comment: Corrected the error, it still doesn't show me all the results (this time I got 2100 results by the way). By inspecting the HTML I can see the data is truly missing, it's not just hidden.

Comment: Really no idea what's goign wrong. I would add some debug info for memory/time: memory_get_peak_usage(true) and probably microtime(true)

Comment: `memory_get_peak_usage(true)` returns firstly 262144 and as I get more and more records it raises to 524288, `microtime(true)` very slowly rises up to 0.116 (approximating) from the starting time. I noticed that the number of records slowly increases for every line of code I add. I don't really know what it's happening. May it be something with php.ini?

Comment: The code is now free of html (except for `<br>` because eyes hurt). It's also ordered by name. It stops inside the `while`, leaving an unfinished string. It reaches row 2122 of 2274. It doesn't display any error but now I'm concerned if the code throws any but they aren't actually sent to me.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to increase max_execution_time limit like this:

```
bool set_time_limit ( int $seconds )
```

The maximum execution time, in seconds. If set to zero, no time limit is imposed.

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Changed the limit to 0, no change.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. It was PhpStorm fault. It works now.